# Stop Centos mailserver from sending spam and route mail to managed mail (G-Suite)

Tags: cpanel, whm, mail-server

We are currently migrating away from hosting our own mailserver due to not having an IT professional who is experienced in mailserver security (SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc.). I have attempted to route the cPanel DNS zone records away from The Server which currently hosts several websites in hopes of fixing the problem of our mailserver being blacklisted for sending spam due to a vulnerability.

I have added Google's TXT records and I can successfully setup G-suite addresses for our email addresses locally.  However, G-suite keeps suspending the email accounts since some spam from our old server (or an email bomb?) keeps being somehow forwarded to the

What steps do I need to take to prevent our mail from our local workstations from being routed through the server? It keeps blacklisting the emails and they can't get to the correct address.

I'm using WHM and cPanel.

Comment: Do you both cPanel and WHM access?

Comment: Yes.  I use both in that stack.  In the "Edit DNS Zones" I went to each Domain and "Email Routing" at the bottom of the page you can strictly specify if the mail is handled locally or remotely.  I just set them all to remote.  Added MX records, SPF, and DKIM as TXT records and good to go.

Comment: Well in this case you should check the Exim Mail Log `/var/log/exim_mainlog` and see from where those emails are coming from. They should be sent somewhere from the server somehow. Maybe there's some trojan on your server or any of the cPanel accounts or sites have been hacked and emails are sent... It's hard to say without actually being able to check what's going on on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WHM "Edit DNS Zones" Go to each Domain and set "Email Routing" at the bottom of the page to "Remotely". Added MX records, SPF, and DKIM as TXT records.

Finally, you can shutdown the dovecot mail application running in Centos.

```
sudo service dovecot stop

sudo service dovecot status
```